# Google Play Problem with my wifi

Tags: google-play-store

Google Play Store not working with my wifi. When I try to update or install apps stuck "Waiting for download". On another wifi working perfectly. And on my wifi with VPN working too, but too slow.
This problem exist on all android device with on my wifi.

Comment: If all Google services do not work this might indicate that your Wifi router has been hacked (there might be other reasons, too, but this is the first that comes into my mind). In such a situation data to certain servers is intercepted. Because PlayStore uses HTTPS with pinned certificates then app download does not work. Use your web browser and check a large number of larger and smaller websites that use HTTPS if there are errors shown regarding certificates.

Comment: Everythig working fine in browser and android app (gmail, google, youtube, etc.) only app install and update not working in play store.

Comment: The only alternative would be that Google has blocked your IP for app download, but for what reason? Also Google typically blocks user accounts, not IPs. But it is worth a  try - power down your wifi router and modem (if you have multiple devices for Internet connection) and then connect them again. This should get you a new IP address and therefore remove existing blockings on IP level.

Comment: 3-4 years ago we have the same IP address. I think static IP though, less often, the modem was turned off for weeks.

Comment: Can you download apps on mobile data?

Comment: yes without a problem.